# Find the Directional Derivatives at (0, 0).

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need to calculate the **maximum and minimum** directional derivatives at $(0, 0).$ The key word here is the maximum and minimum directional derivatives, not just a single directional derivative at $(0, 0).$ The function is:$$f(x, y) = \begin{cases} 
          \frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2} & (x, y) \not= (0, 0), \\
          0 & (x, y) = (0, 0). \\
       \end{cases}$$

The unit vector is just an arbitrary vector $\bar u = (u_1, u_2).$ Using the definition of directional derivatives, I calculated the directional derivative at $(0, 0)$ to be $\frac{u_1^2u_2}{u_1^2+u_2^2}$... So now I need to find the maximum and minimum directional derivatives.

Then I realized this looks really similar to a finding the global maximum and minimum question. So maybe I can try to find the maximum and minimum directional derivative by the Lagrange multiplier algorithm? But I don't have a restriction like $x^2+y^2=4$ for example. So how do I use this algorithm then?

Comment: Have you used the gradient formula $\bigtriangledown f =\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}i+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}j  $

Comment: Or you can write the definition of directional derivative in  $(0,0)$ then...

Comment: I haven't checked if your directional derivative is correct, but assuming it is you can use basic analysis to find its extremal values: you're essentially looking for stationary points of the function, so points where the all the partial derivatives vanish. So calculate the partial derivatives, set them equal to 0 and find all solutions of the resulting system.

Comment: A easier way to see this might be to use polar coordinates, it should be apparent then what directions have the largest and smallest derivatives.

Comment: Your constraint function is that the coordinates are for a unit vector,  so $u_1^2 +u_2^2=1$

Comment: @JoJomax:  That won't work here because $f(x,y)$ is not differentiable at $(x,y) = (0,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your directional derivative is correct. Now simply consider: The direction can be given by an angle $\phi$ so that $u_1=\cos \phi,u_2=\sin\phi$. So then min-max the function
$$ g(\phi)=\frac{\cos(\phi)^2\sin(\phi)}{1} = \cos(\phi)^2\sin\phi = (1-\sin(\phi)^2)\sin\phi$$
for $\phi$. The derivative of this is
$$ \cos(\phi)^3 - 2\cos(\phi)\sin(\phi)^2 $$
This is $0$ if either $\cos\phi=0$ (so $\phi=\pi/2$, $x=3\pi/2$) or if
$$ \cos(\phi)^2 = 2 \sin(\phi)^2 $$
By writing $\cos(\phi)^2 = 1-\sin(\phi)^2$ this turns into
$$ 3\sin(\phi)^2 = 1 $$
or
$$ \phi = \arcsin(\pm\sqrt{1/3}) $$
or the mirrored solutions
$$ \phi = \pi-\arcsin(\pm\sqrt{1/3})$$
(note that as $g$ can be written as function from of $\sin\phi$ we do not need to consider the mirrored $\pi- \ldots$-solutions, as they have the same value as the unmirrored solutions).

For $\phi=\pi/2,\phi=3\pi/2$ we have $g(\phi) = 0$. Also $g(\arcsin(\sqrt{1/3}))$ is $\frac 2 {3\sqrt{3}}$ and $g(\arcsin(-\sqrt{1/3}))$ is $-\frac 2 {3\sqrt{3}}$.

Thus you get by the latter two values the maximal and the minimal value.

The coordinates for these values would be
$$ u_1,u_2 = (\cos,\sin)(\arcsin(\sqrt{1/3})) = (\sqrt{2/3}, \sqrt{1/3})$$
and
$$ u_1,u_2 = (\cos,\sin)(\arcsin(-\sqrt{1/3})) = (\sqrt{2/3}, -\sqrt{1/3}) $$

The two mirrored solutions then of course give us the same with the sign flipped on the cosine, so $(-\sqrt{2/3}, \pm\sqrt{1/3})$, which gives us all four points $(\pm\sqrt{2/3},\pm\sqrt{1/3})$ where those with positive second coordinate would take the maximum and those with negative second corrdinate take the minimum.

Answer (score 0):

The directional derivative is $\frac{u_1^2u_2}{u_1^2+u_2^2}$. As $u_1^2+u_2^2=1$, the (two) extrema of $u_1^2u_2=(1-u_2^2)u_2$ are easily found.